# Server Control or HTML control

Tags: asp.net

i want to know is there any difference between server controls and HTML controls in speed?
for example you want to create a log in page that have two textbox and a button for submitting data,you can do this with both server controls and HTML controls(client_side controls(input) ),do you prefer to use server controls or HTML controls and which one is more efficiently?
which one is faster?

Comment: Do you mean HTML controls with `runat="server"` versus the `asp:` controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server Controls must be executed on the server and a Render method is called to generate the HTML. Therefore they cost a little bit of performance on the server. Depending on the control, they emit data in the ViewState as well, which costs a little bit of additional bandwidth (or very much depending on the control).

It depends on the type of control you want to use. As soon as there is any serverside processing involved (read a textbox, handle a button etc.), I always prefer the asp.net server controls, because they provide much more functionality. But if the control is just sent to the client (such as images, tables, divs etc.) I use HTML controls.

I think the server side processing doesn't take much, it takes a lot longer to get data from a database. Of course it depends on the number of users as well, whether you have to optimize or not. But I would rather use OutputCache instead of not using asp.net server controls.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You always want to validate on the serverside, trusting anything from the client is a big mistake

Comment: +1  Agreed.  Client-side validation is for nice, responsive user experience.  Server-side validation is to protect yourself (your system).  :)

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of server control is that its wrapping a control as a .Net object. It gives you a medium to access your control and its properties from code behind.

HTML controls are usually won't be accessible at client side. However, you can make them available to code behind by adding runat="server" attribute.

With the assumption that you want to access the control from code, you can chose any of them.

Now if you really want to see the difference between the asp.net control (I guess this is what you have referred to as server control) and html control, its the difference between the WebControl and HTMLControl (parents of asp.net and html controls). You basically get two different sets of wrappers. ASP.Net controls come with lot of customization and the control set is a long list than tha HTML controls list.

If we assume that you want to do some basic stuff and there is no need to access the control from code, best thing is the HTML controls, because it would save the rendering effort from the server side.

One more catch here is, if you want to utilize server side resources, such as images stored in server side, you can't access it with simple  consistantly. The postback may lose the path. It would expect a control with runat="server". Its again your choice, html or asp.net controls!!!

Answer (score 0):

Server controls are simple html or combination of html controls with capability to post data to server.

I would prefer server side controls for simple login screen, with preliminary client side validations.

Efficiency of controls depends on the No. of round trips it is making to the server and amount of javascript logic it is executing.